301 bulk redirects using Redirection WP plugin (RegEx option)
I need to redirect a large numbers of similar URLs to a single URL.
For example:
Source: https://www.domain.it/parent1/page-name1, https://www.domain.it/parent1/page-name2, https://www.domain.it/parent1/page-name3 and so on...
To a single page: https://www.domain.it/parent1/
Is it possible to do that in bulk by using a regex expression with redirection WP plugin?
I hope that someone can help me.
Thanks
M
I tried the regex expression
SOURCE: ^/parent1/(.*)
TO: https://www.domain.it/parent1/$1
but it does not work

Try this:
SOURCE: ^/parent1/(.*) TO: https://www.domain.it/parent1/

It doesn't sound like you need to use the captured group, so don't include it in the TO: (by referring to it with the $1)
